# Getting an PHP enum from dynamic name

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

I´m trying to create an php 8.1 enum from a dynamic name. Seems not to be possible. So given an enum

```
enum Foo {
    case bar;
}
```

The following works of course: `Foo::bar` While this doesn´t:

```
$name = "bar";
Foo::${$name}
```

This results in: Access to undeclared static property App\Console\Commands\Foo::$bar

I tried various tricks here, to no avail. It seems not to be possible to get an enum instance from a dynamic name. My custom and quick workaround looks like this, a static factory:

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public static function fromName(string $name) : self {

    foreach(Foo::cases() as $enum){
        if($enum->name === $name){
            return $enum;
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception("Not a valid enum name");
}
```

I could put this in a trait and inherit this in all my enums, yes, problem solved.

My question is: am I missing something here? Is it really not possible to instantiate an enum with native php methods? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

The pre php8.1 class-as-enum composer packages used to have those convenience methods, see https://github.com/bensampo/laravel-enum
So why is this pretty common case not part of the specification (just curious)?

Comment: i think your answer lies [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.object-differences.php). There is a diff list of what you cannot do and what you can do. Moreover there are plenty examples both in comments and in the list of related enum articles. Btw, in your **method**, change `foreach(Foo::cases() as $enum)` to this `foreach(static::cases() as $enum)` so it will be more universal for your multiple enums.

Answer (score 14):

The most simple way for that is using the [constant()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```php
<?php namespace App\Enums;


enum FooEnum: int
{
    case FOO = 123;
    case BAR = 456;
   
    public static function fromName(string $name){
        
        return constant("self::$name");
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```php
$name = "FOO";
dump(App\Enums\FooEnum::fromName($name));

/*
return 
App\Enums\FooEnum {
  +name: "FOO"
  +value: 123
}
*/
```

Comment: this is php 8.1+ please use return value for `fromName`

Comment: @Toskan do you mean return type?

Answer (score 3):

Could you maybe do something like this?

```php
enum Status {
  case OK;
  case DENIED;
}

$name = "OK";
$reflection = new \ReflectionEnum(Status::class);
if ( $reflection->hasConstant( $name ) ) {
  var_dump($reflection->getConstant( $name ));
}
```

Output: `enum(Status::OK)`

Comment: Thank you! This is an alternative option to the method I came up with.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that there isn't a helper method for selecting an enum case by a string value.

Comment: @JacobThomson, maybe https://github.com/henzeb/enumhancer something for you?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could make your enum [backed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php) and use the `::from` method.

```php
// note: type-hinting required
enum Status: int
{
    case OK = 200;
    case ERROR = 500;
}

$statusValue = 200;
$status = Status::from($statusValue);

(returns Status::OK)
```

If you're using Laravel casting, I believe it [requires you](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#enum-casting) to use a backed enum anyway. And in your model you just need to add that cast on your model

```php
...
protected $casts = [
    'status' => \App\Emums\Status::class,
];
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 8.3+

Following syntax is supported since PHP 8.3:

```
<?php

$enumName = 'Something';
SomeEnum::{$enumName};
SomeEnum::{$enumName}->value;
```

This works for both constants and enum **cases**. It was basically done for constants as "dynamic class constant fetch": https://www.php.net/releases/8.3/en.php#dynamic_class_constant_fetch as since enums are basically implemented as a special case of class with special contants (cases) - it works for them too.

### PHP 8.1 & 8.2

You can use `constant()` as you would use for a constant, but be aware of **namespaces!** by the way this is the same issue as with `defined` & `const` definition - *even when inside the namespace, you have to specify it in the reference string!*

#### Namespace example

```
namespace SomeNamespace;
enum MyEnum: int {
    case SomeName = 42;
}

$name ='SomeName';
echo constant("SomeNamespace\MyEnum::$name")->value;
```

#### Simple example (without namespace)

```
enum MyEnum: int {
    case SomeName = 42;
}

$name ='SomeName';
echo constant("\MyEnum::$name")->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```php
$name = 'bar';
$enum = array_column(Foo::cases(), null, 'name')[$name] ?? null;
```