# PHP function to output an array with enum from values

Tags: php, enums, php-8

I receive as input an array of values.
Example : `[3,2,3,1]`
I need as output an array of enums like this : `[Fruits::Banana, Fruits::Pear, Fruits::Banana, Fruits::Apple ]`

I Try to do a generic function to do this but I got an error because `$enumClassName::class` does not work...

```
function get_ennum_array_from_values( array $values, string $enumClassName ){
  $array_of_enum = [];
  foreach ( $values as $value ){
    if( is_numeric( $value ) ){
      $fvalue = (int) $value;
    }else{
      $fvalue = $value;
    }
    $enum = new ReflectionEnum($enumClassName::class);

    if (enum_exists($enum)) {
      $array_of_enum[] = $enum::tryFrom($fvalue);
    }
  }
  return $array_of_enum;
}
```

This how I would like to use it :

```
enum Fruits: int {
  case Apple = 1;
  case Pear = 2;
  case Banana = 3;
}

$array_of_enums = get_ennum_array_from_values( [3,2,3,1], 'Fruits' );
```

How can I do this or fix this function please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an PHP enum from dynamic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018021/getting-an-php-enum-from-dynamic-name)

Answer (score 0):

Can you put class name (with ::class) as second argument? If yes, than

```
function get_ennum_array_from_values(array $values, string $enumClassName) {
  if (!enum_exists($enumClassName)) {
    return [];
  }

  $array_of_enum = [];

  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $fvalue = is_numeric($value) ? (int)$value : $value;
    $array_of_enum[] = $enumClassName::tryFrom($fvalue);
  }

  return $array_of_enum;
}
```

and call it like

```
$array_of_enums = get_ennum_array_from_values([3,2,3,1], Fruits::class);
```